# Properly compile OpenDKIM on Alpine

Tags: compiling, openssl, alpine-linux, opendkim

### Background

Hello, [OpenDKIM](http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html) is available on the [official apk repository](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/community/opendkim/APKBUILD), but does not include important configuration flags I need such as `--with-odbx` and `--with-sql-backend`.

I was able to compile it relatively easily. *However*, the resulting OpenDKIM binary cannot verify DKIM headers since it does not support RSA-SHA256. I found this odd since `apk add opendkim` *does* support RSA-SHA256.

### Question

How can I compile OpenDKIM on Alpine 3.14 with these additional configuration flags *and* still have support for RSA-SHA256?

### Steps to reproduce

First, I pre-downloaded OpenDKIM 2.11.0-Beta2 and OpenDBX 1.4.6 into a `packages` folder.

```bsh
mkdir packages
wget -P packages \
  https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM/archive/refs/tags/2.11.0-Beta2.tar.gz \ 
  http://linuxnetworks.de/opendbx/download/opendbx-1.4.6.tar.gz
```

Then I wrote this `Dockerfile`, based mainly on the [APKBUILD file](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/community/opendkim/APKBUILD).

```
FROM alpine:3.14

COPY packages /opt/data

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    alpine-sdk \
    automake \
    autoconf \
    db-dev \
    libtool \
    mariadb-dev \
    readline-dev \
  && cd /opt/data \
  && tar xzf opendbx-1.4.6.tar.gz \
  && cd opendbx-1.4.6/ \
  && CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/mysql" ./configure --with-backends="mysql" \
  && make install

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    openssl-dev \
    libmilter-dev \
  && cd /opt/data \
  && tar xzf 2.11.0-Beta2.tar.gz \
  && cd OpenDKIM-2.11.0-Beta2 \
  && autoreconf -vif \
  && ./configure \
    --sysconfdir=/etc/opendkim \
    --with-odbx \
    --with-openssl=/usr/lib \
    --with-sql-backend \
  && make \
  && make install
```

Then I built and ran the docker image:

```bsh
docker build -t opendkim-alpine .
docker run opendkim-alpine opendkim -V
```

Notice `rsa-sha256` is missing from the "Supported signing algorithms. Compare to the output here:

```bsh
docker run alpine:3.14 ash -c 'apk add opendkim && opendkim -V'
```

### Notes

- `./configure` failed to complete with an error that libssl could not be found until I specified `--with-openssl=/usr/lib`. I think this may hint that I need to pass `LDFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`, but I don't know what those should be.
- [Debian Buster *does* include the compilation flags I need](https://packages.debian.org/buster/opendkim).
- In the APKBUILD file, I have no idea what the values of `CFLAGS` are and I couldn't easily figure out what `default_prepare` does. It seems relatively opaque and difficult to find the answers to these questions except by experiment.
- I've seen [other attempts](https://github.com/LordVeovis/docker-opendkim/blob/master/Dockerfile) which create an entire alpine build environment and use `sed` to modify the APKBUILD file to include extra flags. This seemed like overkill.
- For Googlers, the error message I get when trying to run opendkim in verify mode is `opendkim: verify mode requires rsa-sha256 support`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I fully don't understand why, but I needed to set this env var for `./configure`:

```bsh
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openssl"
```

So the full `RUN` command becomes:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    openssl-dev \
    libmilter-dev \
  && cd /opt/data \
  && tar xzf 2.11.0-Beta2.tar.gz \
  && cd OpenDKIM-2.11.0-Beta2 \
  && autoreconf -vif \
  && CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/openssl" ./configure \
    --sysconfdir=/etc/opendkim \
    --with-odbx \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-sql-backend \
  && make \
  && make install
```

I resolved this through trial and error and would love an explanation why OpenDKIM couldn't find openssl located there by default.